# Is there a way to add all properties of objects together in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm wanting to do something like:

`{:a => 1, :b => 2} + {:a => 2, :b => 1} = {:a => 3, :b => 3}`

The best solution I can think of thus far is to run sum on each(they're in an array) but i would really prefer to not have to do that many iterations

Answer (score 0):

```
a={:a => 1, :b => 2}
b={:a => 2, :b => 1}

p a.merge(b){|k,v1,v2| v1+v2}
```

Output:

```
{:a=>3, :b=>3}
```

Comment: To give Nate exactly what he wants,  `class Hash; def +(other); self.merge(other) { |_,v1,v2| v1+v2 }; end; end`. Then `a + b #=> {:a=>3, :b=>3}`.